# Ada linker '-mwindows' option kill text output

Tags: gcc, ada

i'am using GNAT GPS 2012. And due some libraries i must use  '-mwindows' option to succesfully link my program (it is actually mixed Ada/C++).

The program works fine in 2 cases:
  1) if launch it via GNAT launcher (i mean the triangle button placed on the top of toolbar) - all is ok in that case
  2) if launch ".exe" separately from windows cmd or explorer and DO NOT OUTPUT ANY TEXT from the Ada side.

But(!) if launch program separately from the windows cmd or explorer than:
  1) call Put or Put_Line function -> the program immediately finish (no errors, no exceptions, just exit)
  2) if call printf from C++ side it will be ignored

I have established in the separate mixed Ada/C++ simple sample that this problem arises when '-mwindows' linker option is added to the Ada linker.

I have also tried to copy dlls from GNAT project to exe folder but it didn't help.

Could you please help me, guys?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to a failure to [start-up the Ada RTL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Interfacing-to-C.html#Interfacing-to-C).

I think the operation you want is `adainit()`.

Comment: @trashgod - Yep, I'm more familiar with it because of a university-project program using .NET and, being slightly rebellious, I did the project using the Ada.NET compiler. {Where you had to call adainit explicitly before using all the RTL stuff.}

Comment: However i think it is not my case because the entry point located in the Ada procedure, not C. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FSF GNAT User Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gnat_ugn_unw/CONSOLE-and-WINDOWS-subsystems.html#CONSOLE-and-WINDOWS-subsystems), `-mwindows` means there is no console; so where would the `Put_Line` or `printf` output go? My guess would be that the Ada call raises an exception, which (silently) ends the program, while the C call effectively does nothing.

If I'm right, though, I have no explanation for the behaviour within GPS.

Comment: GPS on Windows maintains an output console.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you very much! However, the problem is that if i do not put -mwindows i can't link some OpenGL and Windows functions! i'll try to solve the problem in other way and will put the relusts here.

Comment: Yep, seems you right. The program works under GNAT because it does not create console, just use the GPS one (output). If i remove '-mwindows' option i got this:

Comment: libada_gl_sample1.a(glus_windows.o):glus_windows.c:(.text+0x93a): undefined reference to `ChoosePixelFormat@8'
libada_gl_sample1.a(glus_windows.o):glus_windows.c:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
libada_gl_sample1.a(glus_windows.o):glus_windows.c:(.text+0xc9c): undefined reference to `SwapBuffers@4'

Comment: I tryed to link gdi32.lib and libwin32ada.a and some other libs, but nothing helped me. Only '-mwindows' option.

Comment: It's possible to see the command line sent to the system linker, which should give you a clue (Googling ChoosePixelFormat suggests it should indeed be gdi32.lib (.dll? I don't use Windows). In GPS, Project>Edit Project Properties>Switches>Ada Linker and enter `-Wl,-v` in the text area at the bottom (separated by a space from anything that's there already). Then link with `-mwindows` to see how GNAT does it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Simon! This option did help me! I have found "-lgdi32", add it and the program works fine now under console.

Comment: For some reason feading "gdi32.lib" to the linker instead of "-lgdi32" do not works. But, for example, "opengl32.lib" works excelent. Magic for me :) And another magic - GPS "Run" button. It do not works now, cant create any window, hangs... . (if not only 'launch in an external terminal' checkbox is checked).

Comment: But this is neverming, the program works fine now and if using 'launch in an external terminal' checkbox it works under GPS too. Thank you very much!